# Protect python script on Windows server

Tags: python, windows, security, server

I have a bunch of Python scripts which are to be run by several different users. The scripts are placed in a Windows server environment.

What I wish to achieve is to protect these scripts in such a way that standard users are allowed to run them but do not have the rights to read/modify/move them.

Is this even possible and if so what is the optimal strategy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about distributing it - transmute it into an executable binary file. It is easy to make an executable by using the [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It can be installed via PyPi.

`pip install pyinstaller`

One nice thing about PyInstaller is that you can write a Windows Batch Script to make your executable distribution.

Example:

```
@echo off
mkdir dist
mkdir dist/build

pyinstaller ^
--onefile ^
--windowed ^
--workpath=dist\build ^
--distpath=dist ^
--icon="gui\icon.ico" ^
--name="The_Greatest_Prog" ^
the_greatest_script.py

rmdir /S /Q dist\build

cd dist
The_Greatest_Prog
PAUSE
```

What happens here is that the PyInstaller converts your Python Script into one executable file which will show a GUI and has the specified icon. If the arguments `--onefile` and `--windowed` are left out, there will be a small bunch of files like DLLs and the executable file which will show a console. Read the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), especially the [section about usage](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

This Batch Script has to be inside the folder of your Python Script where you simply run it and the result is the file "The_Greatest_Prog.exe" inside the subfolder "dist". You can now give this executable file to your friends without having them ruin your code.

**[EDIT]**

You can also use the standard package [`py_compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html). The output would be a file with the extension ".pyc". Verifiy that the working dirctory is set to the path of your scipt and call this compliler from your preferred Python Console.

```
>>> import py_compile
>>> py_compile.compile("the_greatest_script.py")
```

Then you will see the file "the_greatest_script.pyc" in your folder, which can be distributed and imported by other Python Scripts.

Comment: This sounded promising but after some reading about this approach it seems that a .exe file generated by pyinstaller is relatively easy to revert back to Python code. Isn't this correct?

Comment: Not sure about exe but pyc files can be easily decompiled to py

Comment: Where did you read about reverting from executable to Python? The documentation of PyInstaller even says you can encrypt your executable with [PyCrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto), which uses SHA for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile Python modules into native libraries with Cython and provide compiled files only; though it involves a lot of hassle and doesn't work in some cases. They still can be decompiled to C code but it will be mostly unreadable.

Pros: 1. compiled libraries can be imported as normal Python modules.

Cons: 1. requires additional setup; 2. doesn't work in some cases, e.g. celery tasks cannot reside in compiled modules because: 3. you lose introspection abilities; 4. tracebacks are basically unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to make them not readable but executable at the same time.